# Vue 3 Typescript How to compare string correctly so that it would work?

Tags: arrays, string, typescript, vue.js

I'm doing a project using TS + Vue and I started selecting values from the array returned by the API. It is necessary to compare 2 string values inside the loops, I use === and always get false even with the same values. I tried to make an explicit cast to string, but also did not give any result.

```
const signers: string[] = (transaction.detailedExecutionInfo as MultiSigExecutionDetails).signers;

  console.dir(signers);
  console.dir(confirmations[0].signer);
  console.log('<--->');
  signers.forEach((signer: string) => {
    const signerConfirm = confirmations.filter((confirm: MultiSigConfirmations) => {
      const address1: string = signer as string;
      const address2: string = confirm.signer as string;
      console.dir(address1);
      console.dir(address2);
      console.dir(address1 === address2);
      return signer === confirm.signer;
    });
    console.dir(signerConfirm.length);
  });
```

I even checked directly by comparing two strings with the same values and still get False

```
console.log(signers[0] === confirmations[0].signer);
```

How to compare string primitives in TS correctly?

I attach screenshots from the [console](https://i.stack.imgur.com/bguEp.png).

Thank you all in advance for the answers)

**UPDATE:**

Checked address objects:

```
 console.dir(isRef(address1)); // false
```

`address1` is not a ref object.

**FINAL:**

As I understood string can be just a `literal` or `object{value: "literal"}`. Therefore, I propose to bring them 100% to the literal, for example like this:

```
interface Istr {
  value: string;
}
function convertStringObject(obj: string): string {
  return typeof obj === 'object' ? (obj as Istr).value : obj;
}
```

`convertStringObject` сorrectly processes `strings` and `object-strings`, returning a `literal string`

Answer (score 1):

The comparison in question is:

```js
console.log(address1 === address2)
```

However, those appear to be `ref`s based on the screenshot of the `console.log`.

To correctly compare those `ref`s, use the `value` property of each `ref`:

```js
console.log(address1.value === address2.value)
```

Answer (score 0):

> I tried to make an explicit cast to string, but also did not give any result.

If you're referring to your use of `as string`, that does not change the data type to string; it asserts to TypeScript that the value is already a string. However, that's not so: From your screenshot it appears that `signer` and `confirm.signer` are Objects with a single property, `value`; given your use of Vue, they're likely [Refs](https://v3.vuejs.org/api/refs-api.html). In Javascript and TypeScript, object equality will be based on identity, not value.

If that's true, you're looking for the comparison `address1.value === address2.value`, which will compare strings properly and successfully. You'll also need to `import { Ref } from 'vue'` to get to the `Ref<T>` type, which will properly let you cast `signer as Ref<string>` and `confirm.signer as Ref<string>`.